# Retrieving data from a form loaded with jQuery and passing it to a parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have a 'parent' page that is using the following bit of code to pull in a form from a different page on the same domain. There are reasons why I can't just place the form directly on the 'parent'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#ai_temp_profile_edit").load(
        "https://example.com/form/ #profile-edit-form", 
        function() {}
    ).hide().fadeIn(1000);
</script>
```

The form that is pulled in looks like this:

```
<form action="https://example.com/form/" method="post" id="profile-edit-form" class="standard-form base" target="hiddenFrame">
    <label for="field_1">Name</label>
    <input  id="field_1" name="field_1" type="text" value="Joey-Jojo Jr. Shabadoo">
    <input type="submit" name="profile-group-edit-submit" id="profile-group-edit-submit" value="Save Changes " />
    <input type="hidden" name="field_ids" id="field_ids" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="a62f8d5fec" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/form/" />
</form>
```

When 'submit' is clicked, https://example.com/form/ is opened in a hidden iframe and the user name gets properly saved. This all works well.

I would like the user name on the currently loaded 'parent' page to update via jquery, so that the user has some immediate visual feedback that the name change has taken place.

My approach has been to try and take the value out of the 'field_1' input when 'submit' has been clicked, and pass that variable onto a div in the parent page with an id of 'display_name'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function nameUpdate(){
    $("#profile-group-edit-submit").click(function () {
    var updateName = $("#field_1").val();
    $("#display_name").text(updateName);
    });
}       
nameUpdate();
```

});

I've also tried adding

```
window.parent.
```

before the the #display_name selector section and it didn't change anything.

I've used this approach on another button/div combo on the same page and it works, the difference is that that particular button is in an iframe, not loaded by jquery. So I'm guessing my problem is related to that fact.

I've googled around, but have run out of ideas of how to phrase my question, what to look for, etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: For clarity, the div w/ id #display_name won't update.

Comment: For further clarity, when the source is viewed, none of the form elements actually appear. Only the original jquery code is visible. I put a 'faux form' with identical elements directly on the page and each approach, including the original worked properly.

Comment: I've also tried moving the last piece of code to the same page as the real form but that didn't solve anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to handle the form submission.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#profile-edit-form').submit(function(){ 
    var updateName = $("#field_1").val();
    $("#display_name").text(updateName);
});
});
```

EDIT:

Due to your loading the form dynamically you need to bind the submit function after the load. So...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formLoaded = function () {
        $('#profile-edit-form').submit(function () {
            var updateName = $("#field_1").val();
            $("#display_name").text(updateName);
        });
    };

    $("#ai_temp_profile_edit").load(
            "https://example.com/form/ #profile-edit-form",
            formLoaded
    ).hide().fadeIn(1000);

});
```

Comment: This seems like a better approach, but it still didn't solve the problem. I can't understand why it wouldn't work though.

Comment: I didn't see your edit until just now. I'll give it a shot momentarily. Thanks. :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank's for helping a stranger.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, your problem is "display_name" field is not getting updated with the latest value.
If this is the problem then can you try below thing?

Instead of 
$("#display_name").text(updateName);
try using- 
$("#display_name").val(updateName);

As per the documentation on jQuery site Val() works well with form Elements whereas text won't.

More on Val() method-  https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: You are understanding the problem correctly. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try few more things  - 1) Instead of jQuery try javascript getElementById Function and then use html() to set values. 2) try using innerhtml() property with jQuery code.

Comment: I tried the follow code...didn't even worry about assigning the actual variable yet. It works if I assign it to an element on the actual page, but won't work on any of the actual form elements pulled in by jQuery.

Comment: `function nameUpdate(){
    document.getElementById("profile-group-edit-submit").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("display_name").innerHTML = "New Text!";
    };
    
};
nameUpdate();`

Comment: Can you add your piece of code in JSFiddle and share. That will be easy to find solution on this issue.

Comment: Well here is the fiddle, that accurately represents what i've last tried. However, being cross-domain it doesn't actually pull the form in. So it's basically nothing... I'm pretty sure the problem relates to the form being pulled in from another page.... It's as though the form doesn't actually exist on the parent page and as such, there is a missing link between the form input/button and the receiving div on the parent. https://jsfiddle.net/8opabmp7/1/